# "{ \"Status\":\"N\",\"Result\":\"SessionID is invalid.\",\"StatusCode\":\"NA\"}" vb.net while generating token

Tags: vb.net, wcf

```
 Dim encsec = obj1.Encode(sessID)

            Dim encreq = obj1.Encode(RequestType)
            request.Headers.Add("SessionId", encsec)
            request.Headers.Add("UserName", UserName)
                request.Headers.Add("Password", Password)
                request.Headers.Add("APPID", APPID)
```

Dim randomnumber As Integer = random.[Next](104020, 999999)
sessID = "#@!@#$#" & randomnumber & CustomFund & CustomFundCode

while encoding session id generating not valid ot the length is not matching
and sessid generating code above and example of sessid:#@!@#$#822245171MTc2

this we need to convert into encrypted format

please help me

Answer (score 0):

Web Services Enhancements (WSE) enables the digital signing and/or encryption of SOAP messages. You can read the official Microsoft documentation to achieve your goals. This is the reference:[Encrypting SOAP Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms972410(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: If the response is helpful, please click "accept answer" and upvote it.